# Assigning Object to list of methods

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain to me what this Javascript syntax accomplishes? Tried Googling for it, but I don't know how to form my query. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const {
    assign,
    create,
    defineProperties,
    defineProperty,
    freeze,
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor,
    getOwnPropertyNames,
    getPrototypeOf,
    hasOwnProperty,
    isFrozen,
    keys,
    seal,
    setPrototypeOf,
} = Object;
```

Comment: [Destructuring an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring). It assigns the properties of the object to `const`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const { bar } = foo; // where foo = { bar:10, baz:12 };
/* This creates a constant with the name 'bar', which has a value of 10 */

({ a, b } = { a: 10, b: 20 });
console.log(a); // 10
console.log(b); // 20
```

Reference:

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)